# Adding distances between coordinates in a growing array

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, coordinates, cllocationdistance

I have an array which implements new coordinates every second into my location array. I am trying to add up the distances between each location point and carry this process on as new coordinates are implemented into the array.

I want to use the `CLLocationDistance` function

as an example:

```
var Array = [Double](-1.0, 1.0, -2.0, 2.0, -3.0, 3.0)
```

now I know I can use:

```
let Distance = (Latitude:-1.0, Longitude:1.0.distance(from: (Latitude:-2.0,  Longitude:2.0))

print(Distance)
```

for each point, but I want to use a 'for' statement and indices to calculate all the distances between points of the growing array.

Comment: Wouldn't a `[CLLocationCoordinates2D]` be a better fit for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate distance from two locations

By using

```
let distance = fromLocation.distanceFromLocation(toLocation
```

After Append new distance to total distance